# Show data from API on page load Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to display data from API on page load, but I see in the network tab I got a call but the problem is it does not show in HTML, I don't know where can be the problem, this is what I have for now

**HTML**

```
<div id="models"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var response = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://carportal.azurewebsites.net/api/portal/brand?CountryCode=RS",
        context: document.body,
        success: function () {
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            var output = "<ul>";
            for (var i in json_obj) {
                output += "<li>" + json_obj[i].Name + "</li>";
            }
            output += "</ul>";
            $('#models').html(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post what you are seeing in your rendered HTML, please..?

Comment: Nothing, i see in network all ok, and response, but nothing in HTML?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. *This is not valid `api` url, also note that you should use `https`*

Comment: No try url
http://carportal.azurewebsites.net/api/portal/brand?CountryCode=RS

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Same

Comment: Just tested it on my machine, I ran into the same issue. Unless you're sending the AJAX request from the same domain, the same origin policy will block it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the `response` parameter in the `success` function that's why simple as that

`success: function(){`

to

`success: function(response){`

**EDIT**

Apart from above the `URL` throws

> Failed to load
>   http://carportal.azurewebsites.net/api/portal/brand?CountryCode=RS: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: No, again nothing

Comment: no way man, I just ran your code on local machine with a custom `php` file that responses `json_enocde(['message'=>'All Done'])` and it prints it in the `DOM`.Are you sure, you are not getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error in console ?

Comment: it says the same again `Failed to load http://carportal.azurewebsites.net/api/portal/brand?CountryCode=RS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`